# send and receive picture by xhr javascript

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest, html2canvas

I'm trying to use feedback.js (that based on html2canvas) om my web site (PHP) in order to let users send current screenshot to my email.
but I dont know how to dill with XHR ,JSON... this all new for me

here is how it beeing sent:

```
xhr.open( "POST", this.url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhr.send( "data=" + encodeURIComponent( window.JSON.stringify( data ) ) );
```

how I receive the data in this url, and how send it as **picture** to my email?

Comment: It's not possible. You'll need to use a form with a file input - which is what you'll need anyway, because a file input is the only way to let a user select an image file.

Comment: can you explain more and add code? thank you

Comment: Just a normal form: `<form action="your.php"><input type=file name=file><input type=submit></form>`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can try to convert image to base64 string and send it to server like a simple text data